# How do I run BeyondCompare in X11 as root?

Tags: permission, x11, sudo, wine

I used [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) to install [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) on my Mac.
It runs within an X11 environment. (It works great, by the way.)

But it cannot access many folders to which my user account does not have permission, e.g, in the `/System` folder.

How can I run BC with "sudo" permissions?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used WineBottler, but I'm assuming it creates an icon for the app in your Applications folder.

To run any App in OS X as sudo, open Terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo open -n $foo
```

Then drag the icon for the App from Finder into Terminal (replacing $foo in the example above). Press Enter and type your password. Voilà! Terminal launches the App as root.

Note that open -n works in Terminal to launch any $foo.app as if it were launched via the Finder. (Otherwise it's impossible to launch and OS X app via Terminal as Apps are really just specialized directories on the filesystem-level.)

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
>   Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
> ```
> #1) Respect the privacy of others.
> #2) Think before you type.
> #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
> ```

( I couldn't resist :P )

Comment: This certainly works. I wish I could tick the accepted answer, but we'll need the OP to do that if they are so inclined.